# C# class property validators knowing about neighboring validators

Tags: c#, validation

Given a class with properties, and writing custom validators such as `FooExists`, I'd like to be able to view neighboring validation decorators within my `FooExists` functionality. Unless there's a smarter thing I should be doing instead.

I have custom validators I throw on top of properties in a variety of classes. In some cases I pair it with `[Required]`.

In the scenario where it's *not required*, I'd like to be able to check that within my overriden `IsValid`, and handle it differently.

```
public class ExampleDTO
{
    [Required]
    [FooExists]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherExampleDTO
{
    [FooExists]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public bool IsMoo { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
sealed public class FooExistsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // ideally I could check if this property is required via [Required]

        // look things up in the database, return true or false
        return true;
    }
}
```

This reason for all this is, if I make a POST to a controller receiving an `ExampleDTO`, it will be validated such that Foo exists (Required), and that the value is legal (FooExists). However, if I make a POST to a controller receiving `AnotherExampleDTO`, and leave out the Foo parameter (because it's not required), I don't want it to fail `FooExists`. FooExists can check if it's null, but really I want to say "if not required and null, that's fine, return true."

I have toyed around with adding my own Required property, so that I can `[FooExists(Required=true)]`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
sealed public class FooExistsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public bool Required { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (!Required && value == null)
            return true

        // look things up in the database, return true or false
        return true;
    }
}
```

But this feels wrong, not to mention I lose the free `[Required]` error message.

I'm also trying to avoid (in this case) inheriting IValidatableObject in my DTO and putting this in the model:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    // I could check all of the class properties in here
}
```

Comment: Check out FluentValidation, maybe that could help you not having to deal with custom attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: You could get this behavior with some custom code and reflection, but in the case you have outlined that isn't needed.

The `[Required]` attribute allows you to specify whether empty/null strings are valid. It also only validates strings. To validate an integer you need `Range`.

See: [RequiredAttribute on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3), [RangeAttribute on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

From your example, `[FooExists]` as I said, isn't useful at all because you are working with an integer value. If a field isn't required then there is no need for an attribute at all.

Comment: Range wouldn't tell you if a value was removed or is no longer active.

Comment: Yeah, that should have been a string. Edited.

Comment: Accepting this but appending: the solution for me was to have my custom validators return true if the property's value was null. If you don't want null to pass, well that's why they have [Required] tags, which you use in addition to the [CustomValidator]